# Escape false in Autocomplete

Tags: jsf, primefaces

In Primefaces Autocomplete, the unwanted characters like '&' are displayed and I want to prevent displaying them. In some other controllers I used escape="false" but there is no such escape attribute. How can I achieve this functionality?

Comment: Not sure I understand the problem. How is & an unwanted character? A MCVE would be helpful.

Comment: did you consider espacing the string before passing it to the autocomplete? http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/javadocs/api-2.6/org/apache/commons/lang/StringEscapeUtils.html

Comment: It seems you misunderstand what escaping is.